# The Miss(es) Joneses

Tags: irregular-plurals, appositives, surnames, honorifics

Fowler reads

> *The **Misses** Jones* is the old-fashioned plural, occasionally used when
> formality is required, e.g. in printed lists of guests present, etc.;
> otherwise the type *the **Miss** Joneses* is now usual.

Is *Miss* here a plural ?

Secondly, why can't we use ***Misses** Joneses*?

Finally, is this pattern also used of *Mr., Mrs.* or *Ms.* ?